# How do I insert right justified text in itextsharp?

Tags: itext

I have a PDF into which I need to define very precise rectangles into which I need to inject text. i.e. the PDF is a template and I need to be able to specify a rectangular area and then have text aligned to the bottom of the rectangle and to the right.

I have tried something like this:-

```
PdfContentByte over = ps.GetOverContent(1);
font = new Font(bf, 47, Font.NORMAL, new Color(190, 210, 49));
ct = new ColumnText(over);
myText = new Phrase("3.5", font);
ct.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT | Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, 446.5f, 314.5f, 536.5f, 294.5f, 47, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT | Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
ct.Go();
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong but it doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving absolute positions to the text, why dont you develop a table structure and then place text inside the cells.

Give the alignments and all to the cells

Use **PdfPCell** and **PdfPTable**

Comment: I've got a template to populate with very defined areas the text has to go in. Are you saying create a table in each area?

Comment: No. create a table with such a structure so that you get the cells(rectangles as you are calling) at the exact same places where you want them to be by giving widths and heights to rows and using properties like colspan and rowspan.

Comment: The position is very exact, I am not sure how I could go about doing a table at the exact coordinates. Surely given a columntext with precise co-ordinates it should be possible to insert some right justified and bottom justified text into it?

Comment: try adding a paragraph element at absolute position and give the alignment you want